# Bad performance when added google ads script tag, there is any way to improve performance?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, gatsby

I added the script tag in the **html.js** file in the head tag like that

```
 const ads = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" && (
    <script
      async
      src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"
    />
  )
  return (
    <html {...props.htmlAttributes}>
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta httpEquiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <meta
          name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
        />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css"
        />
        {props.headComponents}
        {ads && ads}
      </head>
       <body {...props.bodyAttributes}>
        {props.preBodyComponents}
        <div
          key={`body`}
          id="___gatsby"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.body }}
        />
        {props.postBodyComponents}
      </body>
    </html>
```

if there is any way to improve the performance of the site I'm thankful.
because when I added this script tag my site performance becomes so bad.

Answer (score 0):

The best option as well as in performance and readability, scalability, and management is to use plugins. Keeping this in mind you have a few approaches:

- Use [`gatsby-plugin-google-adsense`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-adsense/):

  ```
       {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-adsense`,
      options: {
        publisherId: `ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxx`
      },
    },
  ```
- Use Google Tag Manager ([`gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-google-gtag/)) to insert other Adsense or Analytics tags:

  ```
       {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`,
      options: {
        // You can add multiple tracking ids and a pageview event will be fired for all of them.
        trackingIds: [
          "GA-TRACKING_ID", // Google Analytics / GA
          "AW-CONVERSION_ID", // Google Ads / Adwords / AW
          "DC-FLOODIGHT_ID", // Marketing Platform advertising products (Display & Video 360, Search Ads 360, and Campaign Manager)
        ],
        // This object gets passed directly to the gtag config command
        // This config will be shared across all trackingIds
        gtagConfig: {
          optimize_id: "OPT_CONTAINER_ID",
          anonymize_ip: true,
          cookie_expires: 0,
        },
        // This object is used for configuration specific to this plugin
        pluginConfig: {
          // Puts tracking script in the head instead of the body
          head: false,
          // Setting this parameter is also optional
          respectDNT: true,
          // Avoids sending pageview hits from custom paths
          exclude: ["/preview/**", "/do-not-track/me/too/"],
        },
      },
    },
  ```
- Use [`gatsby-browser.js` API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/browser-apis/) to set a script without customizing the `html.js` file. `onClientEntry` function should fit your requeriments:

  ```
  export const onClientEntry = () => <Helmet> <script async
      src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"
    /></Helmet>;
  ```

Comment: "gatsby-plugin-google-adsense" plugin to add auto ads, doesn't help. I will try "gatsby-plugin-google-gtag"

Comment: I've added a third option using `gatsby-browser.js` rather than customizing the `html.js` file.